# BIP39 12 words combination list

Tags: mnemonic-seed

From where I can get bip39 (2048 words) 12 words length possible combinations.

Note: I am not talking about the wordslist of bip39 (2048 words).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From where I can get bip39 ( 2048 words ) 12 words length possible combinations .

There is no such list, because it is simply too large.

From the 2048 words, 12 word mnemonics are 11 words + 1 checksum word. However, the checksum calculation only affects part of the 12th word, so you are still looking at 12 word combinations

This gives you `2048^12`, or `5.44451787e39`. That is a 40 digit long number. Even if you were able to calculate 1 billion combinations per second, it would take you 
`1.726*10^24` years to calculate all combinations, or around `1.3 * 10^14` times the current age of the universe.

Of course, adding in the checksum validation would reduce the list size very slightly, but it would still take you several times the age of the universe to generate that list.